# How to get name into class of div by htmlagilitypack?

Tags: html-agility-pack, win-universal-app

I want to get text into class it like "**pos-4275...**". Definitely, The html agility pack on universal(not silverlight).
I don't have enough for upload photos.Here link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BODRa.png

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
string strhtml = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://");

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(strhtml);
List<SmartThesuarus> arrays = new List<SmartThesuarus>();
var information_content = htmlDocument.GetElementbyId("content");
if (information_content != null)
{
    var cdo_cloud = information_content.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "");
    if (cdo_cloud != null)
    {
        foreach (var node in cdo_cloud)
        {


        }
    }
}
return arrays;
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath isn't available in Html Agility Pack (HAP) version for universal apps, so LINQ is your only option :

```cs
var classValue = "post-4275";
var cdo_cloud = information_content.Descendants("div")
                                   .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                                                .Contains(classValue)
                                          );
foreach (var node in cdo_cloud)
{

}
```

Note that `null` checking on `cdo_cloud` is useless because your `.Where()` method never return `null`. It safely returns sequence of zero item in case there is no item matching the criteria.